# unknown attribute `extern_c` warning in C++

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, extern-c

I’m building a Cocos2d-x game for Android on a Mac, using Android NDK, and I get many warnings like this when compiling the C++ part:

```
/usr/include/module.map:1662:22: warning: unknown attribute 'extern_c' [-Wignored-attributes]
```

Is it dangerous? How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems like http://stackoverflow.com/a/29702983/5333147

Comment: We don’t see any code. It’s hard to tell you how to fix it. :-)

Comment: Probably a missing definition of [`extern_c` macro](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9499107/2157640) or something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that extern_c is a compiler directive for the module map saying it is referencing functions from C++ that were written in the C language (different call frame structure).

The LLVM portion of the CLANG compiler is probably having a version mismatch.
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-maps

Try a command line $ clang -v

You may have to verify the compiler library version
xcode->preferences->locations->command line tools.

Ultimately you will want to clear this up so your stack frames match the arguments and your not referencing a C language function.